# How to get only boxes for specific categories in tensorflow object detection

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

The [object detection notebook](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb) demonstrates, how pretrained and frozen tensorflow models can be used to detect objects in test images.

In this notetook, the function

```
from utils import visualization_utils as vis_util
vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
      image_np,
      np.squeeze(boxes),
      np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
      np.squeeze(scores),
      category_index,
      use_normalized_coordinates=True,
      line_thickness=8)
```

outputs test images, where boxes are drawn around detected objects.

How can I use this function to draw only boxes of a specific category instead of boxes of all categories in the `category_index` set? I.e., how can I get this function to only draw boxes around objects of which the model is sure they are e.g. cars?

Answer (score 11):

This answer may be too late for you. but hope this will help to others.

Inside your **object_detection** folder has folder name **utils** inside that has python file name **visualization_utils.py** you have to edit function named **visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array** on this file. In this function it call function named draw_bounding_box_on_image_array before this add 
**display_str_list = box_to_display_str_map[box]** and add if condition for what will you looking object class. inside this if condition call the draw_bounding_box_on_image_array.(example code given bellow and you can change object detection label names)

```
display_str_list = box_to_display_str_map[box]
if (("bottle" in display_str_list[0]) or ("person") in display_str_list[0]):
  draw_bounding_box_on_image_array(
    image,
    ymin,
    xmin,
    ymax,
    xmax,
    color= color,
    thickness= line_thickness,
    display_str_list=box_to_display_str_map[box],
    use_normalized_coordinates=use_normalized_coordinates)
  if keypoints is not None:
    draw_keypoints_on_image_array(
      image,
      box_to_keypoints_map[box],
      color= color,
      radius= line_thickness /.2,
      use_normalized_coordinates= use_normalized_coordinates)
```